# No such table - EF Core with Sqlite in memory

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to set up my testing environment, but I have trouble with Sqlite adapter. 
Each created context has the same connection so, in-memory databse should be built properly for each context.

But when I'm trying to add something new, it throws error: "No such table: %here_is_my_tablename%".

I think my configuration should be good.

Base:

```
public abstract class BaseServiceTests : IDisposable
{
    protected readonly SqliteConnection Connection;

    public BaseServiceTests()
    {
        Connection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:");
        Connection.Open();
        Assert.NotNull(Connection);

        using (var ctx = BuildCoreContext())
        {
            ctx.Database.EnsureCreated();
        }   

        using (var ctx = BuildWebContext())
        {
            ctx.Database.EnsureCreated();
        }     
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Connection.Close();
    }

    public DbContextOptions<TContext> Options<TContext>() where TContext: DbContext
    {
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TContext>()
            .UseSqlite(Connection)
            .Options;

        return options;
    }

    public ServiceRequestCoreContext BuildCoreContext()
    {
        var ctx = new ServiceRequestCoreContext(Options<ServiceRequestCoreContext>(), null);
        ctx.Database.OpenConnection();

        return ctx;
    }

    public ServiceRequestWebContext BuildWebContext()
    {
        var ctx = new ServiceRequestWebContext(Options<ServiceRequestWebContext>(), null);
        ctx.Database.OpenConnection();

        return ctx;
    }
}
```

Test

```
public class RequestServiceTests : BaseServiceTests
{
    public async Task Prepare()
    {
        using (var ctx = BuildCoreContext())
        {
            await ctx.RequestTypes.AddAsync(new RequestType((int)RequestTypes.Order, "TestType - test"));
            await ctx.RequestStatuses.AddAsync(new RequestStatus((int)RequestStatuses.AcceptedForVeryfication, "test - test", "test - test"));
            await ctx.Companies.AddAsync(new CustomerCompany(1, "test - test", "Test - test"));
            await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task when_creating_new_request_it_should_not_be_null()
    {
        //Arrange 
        await Prepare();
        var customerId = 1;
        var iGen = new IdentifyGenerator();

        //Act
        using (var webCtx = BuildWebContext())
        {
            webCtx.Database.OpenConnection();
            var service = new RequestService(webCtx, BuildCoreContext(), iGen);
            await service.CreateAsync(customerId);
            await webCtx.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        //Assert
        using (var ctx = BuildWebContext())
        {
            ctx.ServiceRequests.Should().HaveCount(1);
            ctx.ServiceRequests.FirstOrDefault().Should().NotBeNull();                
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that the problem is that two separate contexts handles the same SqlConnection. Does it may cause  probles?

Comment: Yes, in case of multiple connections you need to use a shared cache, so your connection string should look like this: `"DataSource=file::memory:?cache=shared"`

Comment: For everybody who stumbles over this question searching for the error message: If you read your connection path from appsettings.json, make sure that it really contains a path and is not empty. There is no error message or exception if the path is empty and it seems like everything works when in reality it does not.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To answer OP, I believe the problem is multiple contexts accessing the database, which doesn't work without a shared cache. Change your connection string to: `"DataSource=file::memory:?cache=shared"`.

For those who wander here from Google, here are some other things to keep in mind:

- At least one connection has to stay open to the database.
- If the database will be accessed from multiple connections, you must use a shared cache as follows: `string connectionString = "DataSource=file::memory:?cache=shared";`
- If using ADO.NET, the official provider does not work properly with Entity Framework. I ran into "no such table" errors while testing even though I had everything configured correctly, but once I changed from: `System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection`(System.Data.SQLite.Core nuget package) to the Microsoft provider: `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection` then the errors disappeared.
- The official Sqlite ADO.NET adapter is **2x times** faster than the Microsoft ones! So unless you absolutely have to, it's better to use the official Sqlite adapter instead.

Example code:

```
[Fact]
public async Task MyTest()
{
    var dbContext = new MyDbContext("DataSource=file:memdb1?mode=memory&cache=shared");

    try
    {
        await dbContext.Database.OpenConnectionAsync();
        // Test your dbContext methods, which has an open connection to the in-memory database
        // If using ADO.NET to make new connections, use Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection
    }
    finally
    {
        await dbContext.Database.CloseConnectionAsync();
    }
}
```

Also remember to [read the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/draft/inmemorydb.html)! :)

**UPDATE:** To make testing easier with the in-memory database, I created a TestContext that inherits from my DbContext in order to automatically handle the connections and db creation: (using NUnit this time)

```
public sealed class TestContext : UsersContext
{
    public TestContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    {
        Database.OpenConnection();
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    public override void Dispose()
    {
        Database.CloseConnection();
        base.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
[Test]
public void AddingUsersShouldIncrementId()
{
    using (var dbContext = new TestContext("DataSource=file::memory:?cache=shared"))
    {
        dbContext.UsersDbSet.Add(new UserEntity());
        dbContext.SaveChanges();

        uint actualId = dbContext.Users.Single().Id;
        Assert.AreEqual(1, actualId);
    }
}
```

Comment: _"The official Sqlite ADO.NET adapter is 2x times faster than the Microsoft ones! So unless you absolutely have to, it's better to use the official Sqlite adapter instead."_ is this still true in 2023? Do you have a source for that?

Comment: @JHBonarius That was just my observation at the time, maybe a bit less than 2x if I remember correctly, but still the difference was significant. Don't know if this is still true in 2023 :)

Comment: I am getting this error on a single connection, the obvious question I have is, do I have to initially create my schema somehow? Or is there some automatic magic that creates my in memory schema?

Comment: Running EFCore and I am running Database.EnsureCreated();

Answer (score 5):

The SQLite In-memory database only exists while the connection is open. You can use different DbContext, but if the connection is closed, the memory db will be deleted.

[Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/sqlite#writing-tests)